# Is there any viable alternative to KettleLifecycleListener in order to track changes to an input schema in a Pentaho plugin?

Tags: pentaho

When building a transformation plugin we've come to the following interesting, but seemingly obvious use case:

A transform step should be able to react to input schema changes and act accordingly.

We've found that there's a [Kettle Lifecycle Plugin](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Kettle+Lifecycle+Plugin) and a planned [`PhasedLifecycleManager`](https://github.com/pentaho/pdi-osgi-bridge/commit/301b88c54f36650e01a0de47b63e5bb2f8c28e4c) that would ostensibly solve for this use case, but no direct support for it yet.

Is there something that we may have missed?